# Trouble with TreeStore in ExtJS 4.0 MVC application

Tags: model-view-controller, tree, extjs4

The new release of ExtJS can make your chrome unstable (Or is it my code?)! Let me explain my situation.

I am working on the new MVC architecture of ExtJS 4.0. I have a tree panel displaying my applications menu or navigation. As per the architecture, I tried to split my tree panel into controller, view and a separate store.

Here is my view:

```
 Ext.define('CRM.view.menu.View', {
    alias: 'widget.menutree',
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',

    initComponent: function() {

        console.log('initComponent of View...');

        Ext.apply(this, {
            title: 'Simple Tree',                       
            width: 200,             
            store: 'MainMenu',
            rootVisible: false
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

My tree's store:

```
 Ext.define('CRM.store.MainMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore', 

    constructor: function() {

        console.log('Constructor of MainMenu TreeStore');

        config = Ext.apply(this,{
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data/menu.json'
            },root: {
                text: 'Menu',
                id: 'src',
                expanded: true
            }
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);

    }
});
```

And in my controller I have provided my store info as well. Here is part of my controller config:

```
Ext.define('CRM.controller.MainMenu',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['MainMenu'],   
    refs: [
        {ref:'menu',selector: 'menutree'},
        {ref:'cp',selector: 'centerpane'}
    ],
        .
        .
        .
```

On initial execution, I get the following error:

> Object MainMenu has no method
>   'getRootNode'

But now, I get more weird error:[image: chrome just fails to display the app]
Notice that chrome stops execution in the constructor of the tree store.

At the same time, in firefox:[image: firefox executes better]
Firefox executes better, but there is no application rendered!

After some trail and error.. I did find a way to get my application running.. and that is to avoid using my store and directly provide the store information as shown below:

```
 Ext.define('CRM.view.menu.View', {
    alias: 'widget.menutree',
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',

    initComponent: function() {

        console.log('initComponent of View...');

        Ext.apply(this, {
            title: 'Simple Tree',                       
            width: 200,             
            store: {
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'data/menu.json'
                },root: {
                    text: 'Menu',
                    id: 'src',
                    expanded: true
                }
            },
            rootVisible: false
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Now the application executes with no issues at all!

Did anybody try creating tree panel using MVC architecture? I have no clue into how to fix this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a known problem!!! Quoting from the [ExtJS forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132794-Trouble-creating-a-tree!):

> The parent class of "Ext.tree.Panel"
>   looks for the store in the store
>   manager in the "initComponent" method,
>   but "Ext.tree.Panel" tries to use it
>   before.

So, One way would be to code your store into your tree another way is to reassign the store in initComponent method. Here is the code:

```
initComponent: function(){
  this.store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(this.store);
  this.callParent(arguments);
}
```