# unable to load data in treepanel of extjs4

Tags: tree, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am new to extjs and I am creating MVC application.

I am trying to create tree panel as following.

Following is my model file

```
Ext.define('rt.model.userinproject', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

proxy: {
    type: 'memory'
},


fields: [
    { name: 'text', type: 'string'},
    { name: 'id',  type: 'Number'}

]
});
```

Following is my store file

```
Ext.define('rt.store.userinproject', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

model: 'rt.model.userinproject',

root: {
        text: 'Project 1',
        id: 1,
        expanded: true
    },

folderSort: true,

sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }],

data: [
        {
            text: "Project 1",
            id: 1, 
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                        {
                            text: "Department 1",
                            id: 1,
                            cls: "folder",
                            children:[
                                        {
                                            text: "User 1",
                                            id: 1,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 2",
                                            id: 2,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 3",
                                            id: 3,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 4",
                                            id: 4,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 5",
                                            id: 5,
                                            leaf:true
                                        }
                                    ]

                        },
                        {
                            text: "Department 2",
                            id: 2,
                            cls: "folder",
                            children:[
                                        {
                                            text: "User 6",
                                            id: 6,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 7",
                                            id: 7,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 8",
                                            id: 8,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 9",
                                            id: 9,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 10",
                                            id: 10,
                                            leaf:true
                                        }
                                    ]


                        },
                        {
                            text: "Department 3",
                            id: 2,
                            cls:"folder",
                            children:[
                                        {
                                            text: "User 11",
                                            id: 11,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 12",
                                            id: 12,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 13",
                                            id: 13,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 14",
                                            id: 14,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 15",
                                            id: 15,
                                            leaf:true
                                        }
                                    ]
                        }

                    ]
        },
        {
            text: "Project 2",
            id: 1, 
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                        {
                            text: "Department 1",
                            id: 1,
                            cls: "folder",
                            children:[
                                        {
                                            text: "User 1",
                                            id: 1,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 2",
                                            id: 2,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 3",
                                            id: 3,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 4",
                                            id: 4,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 5",
                                            id: 5,
                                            leaf:true
                                        }
                                    ]

                        },
                        {
                            text: "Department 2",
                            id: 2,
                            cls: "folder",
                            children:[
                                        {
                                            text: "User 16",
                                            id: 16,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 17",
                                            id: 17,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 18",
                                            id: 18,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 19",
                                            id: 19,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 20",
                                            id: 20,
                                            leaf:true
                                        }
                                    ]


                        },
                        {
                            text: "Department 3",
                            id: 2,
                            cls:"folder",
                            children:[
                                        {
                                            text: "User 21",
                                            id: 21,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 22",
                                            id: 22,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 23",
                                            id: 23,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 24",
                                            id: 24,
                                            leaf:true
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: "User 25",
                                            id: 25,
                                            leaf:true
                                        }
                                    ]
                        }

                    ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Following is my view file

```
Ext.define('rt.view.project.projectuser', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias: 'widget.projectuser',

disabled: true,
border: false,
cls: 'projectuser',
autoScroll: true,

initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        store: this.store,

        items: {
        title: 'User in project',
        }
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
},


});
```

When I am running code, tree panel seems empty without tree.

What I want to do is, I want to show tree based on project id in store above

Let me know if you need any other information from me.

Can anyone help me regarding the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error? Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5933874/185655 It should help you.

Comment: hello Abdel, I checked that code too but currently I am not getting any error.. I was having error of 'me.store.getRootNode is not a function', which I solved from that thread. Currently I have no error. No matter what I am doing nothing is changing actually. I also tried to use ajax proxy as given in example of extjs. But it also loads empty tree. Do you have any other ideas? thanks

Comment: but i don't see you reassigning the store to the tree in `initComponent` method (in the above code)

Comment: Hello Abdel, Thanks for reply. I tried 1-> store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('rt.store.userinproject'), 2-> store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(this.store) and for both I am getting empty tree.. For the above code I am assigning store from controller as var usertree = this.getProjectUser(),store2 = this.getUserinprojectStore(); and assigning store2 to usertree as usertree.store = store2; also I am getting store perfectly in console by console.log(usertree.store); Let me know if you have any other ideas. Thanks

Comment: @Abdel Olakara Also I tried, usertree.data = store2.load(); console.log(usertree.data); and in console I can see data object. But only that tree is not creating and not visible in tree panel for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve above problem by replacing following line in my view file

```
store: this.store,
```

as following,

```
store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('userinproject'),
```

Hope this will help someone.

Thanks.