# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRootNode' of undefined in ExtJs

Tags: extjs4.1

I'm trying to use the Store data which is hardcoded in store to form the tree check tree, but i cannot able to achieve this and i'm getting this error below

I'm new to extjs, can any one aware of this issue.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRootNode' of undefined

```
Store
Ext.define('my.store.ModuleHomeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    autoLoad : false,
    root: {
        text:'test Object Tree',
        id:'TestTreeStoreId',
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
                          "text":"AntiVirus Software",
                          "id":"46",
                          "leaf":"false"
                       },
                       {
                          "text":"Appliance",
                          "id":"68",
                          "leaf":"false"
                       }
                    ]
    },    
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
});
}];

views
Ext.define('my.view.MainTree', {
    extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    width : 400,
    height : 600,
    alias : 'widget.MainTreeTest',
    name : 'mainTree',
    plain: true,
    items : [{
                    xtype: 'pTree',         
                    width:219,
                    height:700,
                    bbar: [{
                            xtype: 'button', 
                            text: 'Cancel' 
                            },{
                                xtype: 'button', 
                                text: 'Ok' 
                            }]
            }]
});


Ext.define('my.view.PreTree', {
    extend : 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    title: 'MyPreference',
    alias : 'widget.pTree',
    id : 'preid',
    store: 'ModuleHomeStore',
    height: 600,
    width: 400,
    multiSelect: true,
    rootVisible : false,
    resizable:false,   
    hideHeaders : true,
    sortable : true,
    xtype:'check-tree'
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created fiddles for you. They have working examples with your code. 
Couple of points, as you know that ExtJs is MVC based framework, so kindly implement everything according to MVC structure.

Only issue related to your code was that in your view:

```
store: 'ModuleHomeStore',
```

is not returning a store instance. One way is to use make use of lookup for store using Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup as done in this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18cn).

Or you can create an instance of store as done [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18cl).

This is also another solution as suggested by another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933874/trouble-with-treestore-in-extjs-4-0-mvc-application). But then you should implement proper controllers and separate your views, stores, models to have full grip over framework.

Comment: I have tired both the solutions, you have suggested, but it does not work. I have used some other way to make it work.

Comment: If i use the Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('test'), it is coming as undefined, when i console it. I have tried  Ext.create('my.store.ModuleHomeStore') this also does not work. With in the buildStore, i tried creating the store and returning it.